# error handling with BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, winforms

I know, that you can handle BackgroundWorker errors in RunWorkerCompleted handler, like in next code

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += (sender, e) => 
    { 
        throw new InvalidOperationException("oh shiznit!"); 
    };
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if(e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error! " + e.Error.ToString());
        }
    };
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

But my problem is that i still receive a message : error was unhadled in user code on line

```
 throw new InvalidOperationException("oh shiznit!");
```

How can i resolve this problem ?

Comment: Do you test this in a WinFormss app? Or Console?

Answer (score 11):

You receive it because you have a debugger attached. Try to start the application without a debugger: no exception is fired and when the worker completes the operation show you the MessageBox.

Comment: Mike came to SO and got the answer he needed. Mike doesn't understand the SO community or the game. Mike didn't mark the answer as correct. Don't be like Mike.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the error. The following works fine:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (s, evt) =>
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("oops");
        };
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, evt) =>
        {
            if (evt.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(evt.Error.Message);
            }
        };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```